# Email does not pass hotmail filter #Update

Tags: spam, email

I have problems sending an email from my server to hotmail it will not pass the junk folder.
This is the header from an email send to hotmail:

```
x-store-info:4r51+eLowCe79NzwdU2kR3P+ctWZsO+J
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=none (sender IP is 198.27.65.125) smtp.mailfrom=info@bitcoin-24.com; dkim=none header.d=bitcoin-24.com; x-hmca=none
X-SID-PRA: info@bitcoin-24.com
X-AUTH-Result: NONE
X-SID-Result: NONE
X-Message-Status: n:n
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0xO0Q9MjtHRD0yO1NDTD0x
X-Message-Info: z6+tzUa3IoQ4STm4n9SvUxtBxj2LBDMotFMQN0CeMLY1ltec70GGjrtYaRlQu6sSgGdqLAlHJkr+cCvfFCPQGi9l4HYJlRlRP0rm7lgVh/YYKD5AV8gh8pG5mTPq7K95xSy1Kiq/dGAcxGpNRez+0NozvHyqV9Tz
Received: from mail.bitcoin-24.com ([198.27.65.125]) by SNT0-MC3-F35.Snt0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4900);
     Tue, 12 Mar 2013 06:43:26 -0700
Received: from localhost (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by mail.bitcoin-24.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 52E47478A071
    for <tais46@hotmail.de>; Tue, 12 Mar 2013 14:43:25 +0100 (CET)
X-Virus-Scanned: Debian amavisd-new at mail.bitcoin-24.com
Received: from mail.bitcoin-24.com ([127.0.0.1])
    by localhost (direct.bitcoin-24.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with ESMTP id kGh63GF6X1rR for <tais46@hotmail.de>;
    Tue, 12 Mar 2013 14:43:24 +0100 (CET)
Received: from marc-macbook.fritz.box (brln-4dba143d.pool.mediaWays.net [67.186.84.61])
    (Authenticated sender: info@bitcoin-24.com)
    by mail.bitcoin-24.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 243A0478A06F
    for <tais46@hotmail.de>; Tue, 12 Mar 2013 14:43:24 +0100 (CET)
From: Simon Hausdorf <info@bitcoin-24.com>
Content-Type: multipart/signed; boundary="Apple-Mail=_596436D1-A690-407A-94C1-450EC05F3011"; protocol="application/pgp-signature"; micalg=pgp-sha1
Subject: test
Message-Id: <3180C6FE-50B1-4E38-8539-8645A5D90579@bitcoin-24.com>
Date: Tue, 12 Mar 2013 14:43:23 +0100
To: tais46@hotmail.de
Mime-Version: 1.0 (Mac OS X Mail 6.2 \(1499\))
X-Mailer: Apple Mail (2.1499)
Return-Path: info@bitcoin-24.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 12 Mar 2013 13:43:26.0947 (UTC) FILETIME=[92EC5330:01CE1F27]
```

**UPDATE**

```
x-store-info:4r51+eLowCe79NzwdU2kRwMf1FfZT+JrTmuGtRwCGqPtfRrGlBm2fuIYvdrbUPodaYxPNBi8Xobg36A3glSNG0rF6WRq6gR2mFyk2EU695X7fpOd4ThQ6G+KTf3YllqVtBgcoL7NGkI=
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is 198.27.65.125) smtp.mailfrom=info@bitcoin-24.com; dkim=pass header.d=bitcoin-24.com; x-hmca=pass
X-SID-PRA: info@bitcoin-24.com
X-AUTH-Result: PASS
X-SID-Result: PASS
X-Message-Status: n:n
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0xO0Q9MjtHRD0yO1NDTD0w
X-Message-Info: z6+tzUa3IoTXR87giofdF1iMOF3scDQR7jXVxH22P1eNFe0zoMRvZ/vN/vUr7xz/Otogt0AUoI+R18ESw4+xnNiL/fS2IQQ0cZOG9R378gEbTa4Jkj/ksSqOvXGy46lglL5bXS2D7hkxBxQyPCt+wmlds2wl7AHa
Received: from mail.bitcoin-24.com ([198.27.65.125]) by SNT0-MC4-F9.Snt0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4900);
     Tue, 12 Mar 2013 13:40:31 -0700
Received: from localhost (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by mail.bitcoin-24.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 44E6F478A071
    for <tais46@hotmail.de>; Tue, 12 Mar 2013 21:40:30 +0100 (CET)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple; d=bitcoin-24.com;
    s=default; t=1363120830;
    bh=Uxt0+a9s0JyiyB3JcPuVGEeaeZpSHDxfQY8n370lgRU=;
    h=From:Content-Type:Subject:Message-Id:Date:To:Mime-Version;
    b=TprtE030Swlg6jL9rKE8Z25GwlbDuuQTMeR8XormYfhcFMaKx1MsHkeVPfaNMIq2t
     I/D7+xYd922TdrPALzcRjqiGPAc4PGRgdvcLlGOpUB9n1MjX3X4vf2/x6zm/NSCudY
     O6ZHB1vpzp+fqXJFjRNWK36U9UTroMObXEbIxxNA=
X-Virus-Scanned: Debian amavisd-new at mail.bitcoin-24.com
Received: from mail.bitcoin-24.com ([127.0.0.1])
    by localhost (direct.bitcoin-24.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with ESMTP id 1nO8HI0YmU1o for <tais46@hotmail.de>;
    Tue, 12 Mar 2013 21:40:29 +0100 (CET)
Received: from ***-macbook.fritz.box (brln-4eba543d.pool.mediaWays.net [76.186.84.61])
    (Authenticated sender: info@bitcoin-24.com)
    by mail.bitcoin-24.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 69435478A06F
    for <tais46@hotmail.de>; Tue, 12 Mar 2013 21:40:29 +0100 (CET)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple; d=bitcoin-24.com;
    s=default; t=1363120829;
    bh=Uxt0+a9s0JyiyB3JcPuVGEeaeZpSHDxfQY8n370lgRU=;
    h=From:Content-Type:Subject:Message-Id:Date:To:Mime-Version;
    b=QnUjNP6XE75cjSlcnCW7WT2P5ZqMnHywfhEi8KZJL4VfRZyqART4ofd8HSm4CuHAi
     kVWwl3TdfS6yhJC01PJApebALKrilxu1w5eAeX03NysrBbKTdJET0FmziRzuWczu5Q
     lqT48hzjNxRgID3xrJaTJ10h25mdg2Jadzc/yrkI=
```

Answer (score 2):

You have no SPF record on bitcoin-24.com, and most likely no DKIM either. These are good first steps.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Comment: set the SPF record, but it does not help.
will take a look at DKIM

Comment: It does help, spam's just a multi-factor situation. The more anti-spam things you implement, the better.

Comment: Have now SPF and DKIM running, but the emails does not pass trough hotmail :( - take a look at the update

Comment: Try sending more legitimate-looking e-mail than a subject of "test". Content analysis plays a role, too. Hotmail is notoriously strict on inbound e-mail.

Comment: tried again but does not work. I think that the hotmail spam filter is very bad! Just saw that the account of my girlfriend have a lot of spam mails from serious companies, which are not spam

Answer (score 1):

Your forward and reverse DNS match.  This is good.

Your `mailname` (`mail.bitcoin-24.com`) doesn't match the reverse DNS.  This may not matter much as the forward lookup for that domain does match.

[Your reputation is fine](https://www.senderscore.org/lookup.php?lookup=198.27.65.125&ipLookup.x=0&ipLookup.y=0).

Implementing [DKIM](http://www.dkim.org/), [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) and [DMARC](http://www.dmarc.org/) may help delivery.  Hitting the "Not junk" button in Hotmail might too.